# Node.JS equivelant to getContextPath, getServletPath?

Tags: node.js, http, routes, contextpath

I'm working on a webserver, which will load various modules for various 'web applications' on the same domain.

In the following example,

```
createServer(function (req, res) { // crude request routing example
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname
  if(path.match(/^\/cats(?:\/|$)/))
    require('./cats.js')(req, res)
  else if(path.match(/^\/dogs(?:\/|$)/))
    require('./dogs.js')(req, res)
  else
    require('./404.js')(req, res)
})
```

the if statement checks for a matching context path, and routes it to the appropriate module.

Now the module `cats.js` looks something like this:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname
  // HOW can I get context path and path info? What variables should I use?
  if(req.path == '/cats/add') {
    //....
  } else if(req.path == '/cats/delete') {
    //....
  } else
    // 404
}
```

The problem is, down the road I will be updating the context path, so instead of `/cats`, users will have to go to `/somethingelse` to get to `cats.js`

For this reason, `cats.js` should not be checking for `/cats/add`, but should instead look for `$CONTEXT/add`.

What is a good way to pass the 'context path' and the 'path info' to `cats.js`? I'm thinking about making something up and tacking it onto the `req` object, but surely this is a common problem and there is a generally accepted correct solution?

Comment: Consider the `express` module.  It implements a concept of route handlers (connect style middleware) which can be mounted at arbitrary context paths.  The latest version, 4 goes a step further, allowing complex Router code to be mounted like any other middleware.

Comment: `express` is not something I want to include on the front end as this would interfere with my 'process management' and 'http to stdio' modules. However, I would like to stay consistent. How would `cats.js` be written in express, and how would the handler be able to distinguish the 'context path' from the 'path info'?

Comment: Unfortunately, express needs to be the callback to your http server.  It's kind of unfortunate that what your asking has completely been implemented in a module.  More to you're original question, in an express server there is no context path per se.  The callback to createServer handles all requests.  This is a departure from a framework like J2EE where a container decides which servlet gets which request based on a URL prefix.  tl;dr, you're writing the equivalent to that container.  Either use express, or do what express does:

Comment: I'm following up on this now. I'm ready to include express in my server if possible under my setup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090240/express-js-with-my-own-http-listener

Comment: I see that express uses [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) for the context path.

Comment: So, you could have some string in a cfg file and use that in your `app.use()` call..then not need cfg file from within the router itself (just read `req.baseUrl`)

Answer (score 1):

You could have `cat.js` export a function which takes a path arg and uses it to create the request handler on the fly:

```
module.exports = function(context){
  return function (req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname
    if(req.path == '/'+context+'/add') {
      //....
    } 
    //....
  }
}
```

As others mentioned, Express.JS has this capabilities built in and would be a generally accepted solution, other than that you're free to roll however you want.