# Express.JS with my own HTTP listener?

Tags: node.js, express

I have my own HTTP listener, which then serializes the request, passes it to another process which deserializes, and handles the I/O between, preserving the Node.JS HTTP `req`/`res` API.

**Is it possible for me to pass my recreation of vanilla `req` and `res` objects to express?**, allowing express to add its handy functions (like `res.send`), and to take over routing, and add middleware?

Comment: By 'own', you mean not derived from node core `http.Server`?  Maybe [custom Express middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) applied to every req (don't specify a path) could eliminate need for homeroll HTTP server

Comment: The `http.Server` is used, but it is in a different process. The `stdin`/`stdout` are used as the data transfer mechanism for serialization. The process which express would run within actually has different user permissions, and can be killed separately from the listener, etc. A wildcard middleware wouldn't be useful because Express.JS functions could not be included in the serialization process, only afterward.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is straight-forward to do. Not yet tested.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
http_to_stdio.on('request', app.handle)
```

I just have to make sure I am properly re-creating the methods found in `http`'s implementation of `req` and `res`.